# Open and Close PowerShell from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a macro enabled Excel spreadsheet that will run commands and log to a file.  I would like to read this file in real time to monitor the status.   I figured out how to open PowerShell and tail the file, now I would like to close the PowerShell window at the end of the macro.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Below is an example of what my macro is doing.

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim LogFile as String, Command as String

LogFile = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
'I did have -noexit before, I removed it and PowerShell remains open when sub ends.
'Command = "PowerShell -noexit -command ""get-content '" & LogFile & "' -Tail 0 -wait"""
Command = "PowerShell -command ""get-content '" & LogFile & "' -Tail 0 -wait"""

'Create LogFile
Set fsoScript = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fileout = fsoScript.CreateTextFile(LogFile, True, True)
Fileout.Write ""
Fileout.Close

'Run PowerShell to tail LogFile
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run Command, 1

'Update Logfile
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set Fileout = fsoScript.OpenTextFile(LogFile, 8, True, -2)
Fileout.Write Now() & " - test1" & vbCrLf
Fileout.Close

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set Fileout = fsoScript.OpenTextFile(LogFile, 8, True, -2)
Fileout.Write Now() & " - test2" & vbCrLf
Fileout.Close

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set Fileout = fsoScript.OpenTextFile(LogFile, 8, True, -2)
Fileout.Write Now() & " - test3" & vbCrLf
Fileout.Close

Msgbox "Done"
End Sub
```

I have tried the following, but I could not get it to work.

```
PID = objShell.Run Command, 1
```

I was thinking if I had the PID then i could kill it at the end.

Comment: if you mean to capture a return value from a function, you need the parentheses: `PID = objShell.Run(Command, 1)`

Comment: I tired `objShell.Run(Command, 1)` but it only returns a 0 not the PID that would be needed to kill the process.

Comment: I was just pointing out the correct syntax for capturing the result of a function call in VBA. From a quick Google search it looks like people usually have the opposite problem, i.e. Powershell closes automatically after running a script and they'd want to keep it opened. I'd look into the command-line arguments, there's probably a switch to toggle this behavior.

Comment: I thank you for your input, I appreciate it.  I just realized my response may have been a little dismissive, that was not my intent at all.  I was just letting you know I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: I did find something that looked promissing however it triggered my antivirus software and botted me out of excel.  `vPID = Shell(Command, vbNormalFocus)`  So I cant use this.

Comment: Can the script be modified to include a `stop-process -Id $PID` command?

Comment: I did add the following to the end of the script.  However this will kill any powershell windows not just the one opened by this process.  `Shell "TASKKILL /F /IM powershell.exe"`  I will keep trying to figure out a more targeted approach, any assistance would be greatly appriceiated.

Comment: `$PID` _is_ your target

Comment: I would like to stop it by the PID, the problem is I do not know how to obtain the correct PID to stop.

Comment: No I mean _literally_ - from what I gather `$PID` is a variable accessible _within the PowerShell script_ that refers to its own process ID

Comment: The issue is how do I get the PID into a variable when I run the command so that it can be killed later.

Comment: Admittedly didn't test it, but from what I gathered, it's built-in. `$PID` would be readily available to use.